# How can I bind label content with value from query?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to bind the content of a label based on the result I get from running a stored procedure. Here is my XAML:

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Label Content="Date:" FontSize="10" />
    <Label x:Name="HomeScreenLabelInfoDate" FontSize="10" FontWeight="DemiBold" FontStyle="Italic" Content="{Binding InfoDate}"/>
    <Label Content="-"/>
    <Label Content="Author:" FontSize="10"/>
    <Label x:Name="HomeScreenLabelInfoAuthor" Margin="3 0" FontSize="10" FontWeight="DemiBold" FontStyle="Italic" Content="{Binding InfoAuthor}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And here is my code-behind:

```
public HomeUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    try
    {
        GetPublications();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public class NewsData
{
    public string InfoTitle { get; set; }

    public string InfoMessage { get; set; }

    public string InfoDate { get; set; }

    public string InfoAuthor { get; set; }
}

public void GetPublications()
{
    string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;

    using (var Connect = new SqlConnection(connstr))
    {
        Connect.Open();
        using (var Command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[spNewsManagementTb_DisplayNews]", Connect))
        {
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Command.Parameters.Add("@entity_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LoggedInData.LoggedInstitutionId;
            SqlDataReader dr = Command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string newsTitle = dr.GetString(0);
                string newsMessage = dr.GetString(1);
                string newsAuthor = dr.GetString(2);
                DateTime newsDate = dr.GetDateTime(3);
                string newsDateFormated = newsDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");

                NewsData newsData = new NewsData();
                newsData.InfoTitle = newsTitle;
                newsData.InfoDate = newsDateFormated;
                newsData.InfoAuthor = newsAuthor; 

            }

            dr.Close();
            Connect.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the application, I don't see any data on my GUI. I have been able to overcome this by directly assigning the values of the labels from the values read from query but I would like to keep on using data binding throughout the code for consistency but this one is proving quite difficult to implement.

**EDIT**

I would like to mention that I am a beginner in programming so I am not really good at understanding all the concepts but the INotifyPropertyChanged property has thrown multiple errors. Here is the code after including the Notify property:

```
public HomeUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    try
    {
        var newsData = GetPublications();
        this.DataContext = newsData;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public NewsData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string Title;

        private string Message;

        private string Date;

        private string Author;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public NewsData(string infoTitle, string infoMessage, string infoDate, string infoAuthor)
        {
            this.Author = infoAuthor;
            this.Date = infoDate;
            this.Message = infoMessage;
            this.Title = infoTitle;
        }

        public string InfotAuthor
        {
            get { return Author; }

            set
            {
                Author = InfotAuthor;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string InfotDate
        {
            get { return Date; }

            set
            {
                Date = InfotDate;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string InfotMessage
        {
            get { return Message; }

            set
            {
                Author = InfotMessage;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string InfotTitle
        {
            get { return Title; }

            set
            {
                Author = InfotTitle;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string Author = null, string Message = null, string Date = null, string Title = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Author));

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Message));

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Date));

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Title));
        }
}

public NewsData GetPublications()
{
    string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;

    using (var Connect = new SqlConnection(connstr))
    {
        Connect.Open();
        using (var Command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[spNewsManagementTb_DisplayNews]", Connect))
        {
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Command.Parameters.Add("@entity_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LoggedInData.LoggedInstitutionId;
            SqlDataReader dr = Command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string newsTitle = dr.GetString(0);
                string newsMessage = dr.GetString(1);
                string newsAuthor = dr.GetString(2);
                DateTime newsDate = dr.GetDateTime(3);
                string newsDateFormated = newsDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");

                NewsData newsData = new NewsData();
                newsData.InfoTitle = newsTitle;
                newsData.InfoDate = newsDateFormated;
                newsData.InfoAuthor = newsAuthor; 

            }

            dr.Close();
            Connect.Close();
        }
    }

 return newsData;
}
```

The errors are arising from the GetPublications() method, which does not recognise NewsData

Comment: NewsData needs to support [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://intellitect.com/getting-started-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-pattern-using-windows-presentation-framework-wpf/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make following changes to your code.

1. Make GetPublications() to return "NewsData" type like below,

   ```
   public NewsData GetPublications()
   {
       string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;
       NewsData newsData = new NewsData();

       using (var Connect = new SqlConnection(connstr))
       {
           Connect.Open();
           using (var Command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[spNewsManagementTb_DisplayNews]", Connect))
           {
               Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               Command.Parameters.Add("@entity_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LoggedInData.LoggedInstitutionId;
               SqlDataReader dr = Command.ExecuteReader();
               while (dr.Read())
               {
                   string newsTitle = dr.GetString(0);
                   string newsMessage = dr.GetString(1);
                   string newsAuthor = dr.GetString(2);
                   DateTime newsDate = dr.GetDateTime(3);
                   string newsDateFormated = newsDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");


                   newsData.InfoTitle = newsTitle;
                   newsData.InfoDate = newsDateFormated;
                   newsData.InfoAuthor = newsAuthor; 

               }

               dr.Close();
               Connect.Close();
           }
       }

       return newsData;
   }
   ```
2. In code-behind (constructor) of your user-control do the following changes,

   ```
   public HomeUserControl()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       try
       {
           var newsData = GetPublications(); 
           this.DataContext = newsData;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged for NewsData class. See below link on how to achieve this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

Small suggestion :- I prefer to make my database call in async way so that my user-control loads and waits for the data to come and bind.

Give a try and let us know if you still have further any issues.

**Edit:-** - Added extra piece of code after updated question.

Hi,
I have seen some mistakes from your code.

1. In your .xaml you are using "InfoDate" and "InfoAuthor" to bind to your label's. 
   But your NewsData does not have those properties.

Your NewsData properties names are "InfotAuthor" and "InfotDate" - **It has "t" in it**

2. I have used your xaml code (after making above changes).

Without INotifyPropertyChanged inheritance, I am able to see the data. I guess if you make above changes then you should be able to see the data in your view.

3. If you want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, you can follow as below,

   public class NewsData : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       private string _title;

   ```
   private string _message;

   private string _date;

   private string _author;

   public string InfoAuthor
   {
       get { return _author; }

       set
       {
           _author = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("InfoAuthor");
       }
   }

   public string InfoDate
   {
       get { return _date; }

       set
       {
           _date = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("InfoDate");
       }
   }

   public string InfoMessage
   {
       get { return _message; }

       set
       {
           _message = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("InfoMessage");
       }
   }

   public string InfoTitle
   {
       get { return _title; }

       set
       {
           _title = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("InfoTitle");
       }
   }

   protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
   {
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   ```

   }

> I have made private members to start with "_" with camel casing (this is just correct naming conventions for back-end fields)
>
> I have implemented OnPropertyChanged() method and I am calling from each property setter method.
>
> In your setter method, you are trying to set like below which is wrong,

```
Date = InfotDate;
```

You need to set as **"Date = value;"**

Hope you can understand the difference from my updated answer.

Give a try and let us know in case if you still have any other issue.

If it answers your question then kindly accept it as answer.

Comment: Hi G K, The Notify property made more difficult to me implement, mainly because I am not very familiar with mvvm. I have updated the question with the new code

Comment: Hi, after the changes are you able to display the data. Also some properties in your NewsData is wrongly mapped with backend fields. See InfotTitle and InfotMesaage. And what errors are you facing? DataContext is the feature which helps to reduce lot of code to bind to and from UI to your ViewModel.

Comment: Hi, after the changes are you able to display the data. Also some properties in your NewsData is wrongly mapped with backend fields. See InfotTitle and InfotMesaage. And what errors are you facing? DataContext is the feature which helps to reduce lot of code to bind to and from UI to your ViewModel.

Comment: I am getting an error at the return newsData; => Does not exist in the current context

Comment: That's because you are missing this statement "NewsData newsData = new NewsData(); " in your GetPublications() method. See after connStr statement.

Comment: True. The errors are gone but still can't display the data. Might this be due to the fact that I have incorrectly implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged? I didn't include the [CallerMemberName] because I didn't know what to put there

Comment: I will try to make changes to your code and update my answer in sometime. Right now I am on mobile.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thanks

Comment: It works now. Thanks for your Help :). As a beginner, I thought that MVVM was supposed to make your coding easier but it looks to me like it complicates more than it simplifies. When I just assigned the values of the labels from the GetString method like this: ```HomeScreenLabelInfoTitle.Content = newsTitle;```, the code was way shorter than what we just implemented... Why go MVVM?

Comment: Great it worked. MVVM benefits you a lot when you have two way bindings and when your property changes, it automatically updates your UI and many more benefits are there with it. Read about it and start practicing with it.